# How to square items on Listbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-c#-express-2010

Is there a way to `square` the items on a `listbox` then the output would go to the other `listbox`

for example I added an item on the `listbox` using loop

```
int items;
items=2;
do
{
    listbox1.items.add(items);
    items=items+2;
} while(items<20);
```

Comment: "for example I added an item on the listbox using loop".... and?

Comment: I don't see any _square items_ code.. What is `i`?

Comment: Isn't that an infinite loop?

Comment: I mean, the output on the listbox1 would be 2,4,6,8 until 20 then The all of the items on the listbox1 will be squared and the output on listbox2 is 4,16,36 until 400

Comment: Could you please explain more your problem ? in the code provided in your post i don't see any code that square the number, and the loop seems like infinite, we'll never rich the condition since the number don't change in the loop !

Comment: http://puu.sh/bifan/e48af0b980.png this is the example, what I want to happen is get the items inside listbox1 get^2 and the squared items would go to listbox2

Comment: Instead of `i=i+2`, did you mean `item=item+2` ? Or maybe `item^2` since you want to square it?

Comment: `int items;
items=2;
do
{
    listbox1.items.add(items);
    itemsTemp = Math.Pow(items, 2);
    listbox2.items.add(items);
    items += 2;
} while(items<20);`

Comment: i mean item=item+2 i dont know who edited it into i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add `4, 16, 36, ... 324` items, you can achieve it with the code:

```
for (int i = 2; i < 20; i += 2) 
  listbox1.Items.Add(i * i);
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the image you posted in a comment to Abdelhamid's answer it looks like you are trying to populate the items in the second list box as the squared version of their counterparts in the first list

```
foreach(var item in listBox1.Items)
{
    //Since you don't specify their type I presume they need parsing..
    int num;
    int.TryParse(item.ToString(), out num);
    listBox2.Items.Add(num * num);
}
```

If you were trying to do it at the same time as populating the first..

```
int items = 2;
do
{
    listbox1.Items.Add(items);
    listbox2.Items.Add(items * items);
    items += 2;
} while(items<20);
```

Comment: this was the thing that I've been trying to think on how to make each items into a varialble

Comment: No worries, its possible that they are stored in the listbox items as integers already, negating the need to parse

Comment: how to make this as the best answer?

Comment: Since the items in the listbox are still of type `int`, there is no need for parsing. Instead cast, because they are returned as `object`: `foreach (object item in listBox1.Items) { int num = (int)item; listBox2.Items.Add(num * num); }`

Comment: Yes as @OlivierJacot-Descombes states or `foreach( int item in listBox1.Items.Cast<int>())`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ListBox` for display and for user interaction only and do the logic operations independently from the listbox.

```
// Initialize
List<int> input = new List<int>();
for (int i = 2; i < 20; i += 2) {
    input.Add(i);
}

// Calculate
List<int> result = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < input.Count; i++) {
    int value = input[i];
    result.Add(value * value);
}

// Display
listbox1.Items.AddRange(input);
listbox2.Items.AddRange(result);
```

The GUI (Graphical User Interface) logic should always be kept separate from the so called Business Logic (in this case the calculation of squares). The `List<int>`s represent the data in the business logic (they are called the Model). They are typed and need no casting or transformation and do not depend on some controls. If you want to convert your example into a web page, the business logic part will remain exactly the same, where as the display part will be completely different.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
int items =2;
int items_sq;
do
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(items);
    items_sq=Math.Pow(items,2); //squares the items variable
    listBox2.Items.Add(items_sq);    
    items += 2;
} while(items<20);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int items;
items=2;
do
{
    listbox1.items.add(items);
    items = Math.Pow(items, 2)
} while(items<20);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
int items;
items=2;
do
{
    listbox1.items.add(items);
    listbox2.items.add(items*items);
    items=items+2;
} while(items<20);
```

Comment: this works too, same output as the best answer. Thank you Sir :)